# snakemake: How to use glob_wildcards for newly created files?

Tags: python, snakemake

The problem:

I have a large workflow which creates at some point an arbitrary number of files per `{sample}`, named e.g. `test1.txt`, `test2.txt`, etc.

I then need to use these files for further processing. The input files for the next rule are then `{sample}/test1.txt`, `{sample}/test2.txt`, etc. Thus `test1`, `test2`, etc become wildcards.

The data structure is:

```
---data
 ---sample1
   ---test1.txt
   ---test2.txt
   ---test3.txt
 ---sample2
   ---test1.txt
   ---test2.txt
Snakefile
```

I am struggling how snakemake can be used for such problems. I have looked into the function `glob_wildcards`, but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Intuitively, I would have done something like this:

```
samples = ['sample1', 'sample2']

rule append_hello:
  input:
    glob_wildcards('data/{sample}/{id}.txt')
  output:
    'data/{sample}/{id}_2.txt'
  shell:
    " echo {input} 'hello' >> {output} "
```

I have two questions:

1. How can this problem be handled in Snakemkae?
2. How would you construct a `rule all` in order to run this.

Any inputs or any hints into further reading would be appreciated.

## Edit

I think it has to do with wildcard constraints. When I run:

```
assemblies = []
for filename in glob_wildcards(os.path.join("data/{sample}", "{i}.txt")):
    assemblies.append(filename)
print(assemblies)
```

I get two lists where the corresponding index matches:

```
[['sample1', 'sample1', 'sample1', 'sample2', 'sample2'], ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test5', 'test4']]
```

Now I basically only need to tell snakemake to use corresponding wildcards values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You problem is that `glob_wildcards` is evaluated only once before any rule is executed, so the system doesn't know how many files would that rule generate.

What you need is a [checkpoint](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution). This feature allows you to stop Snakemake on some point and reevaluate the DAG.

```py
samples = ["sample1", "sample2"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("data/{sample}/processed.txt", sample=samples)


checkpoint generate_arbitrary:
    output:
        directory("data/{sample}/arbitrary")
    run:
        if wildcards.sample == "sample1":
            n = 3
        else:
            n = 2

        shell("mkdir {output}")
        for id in range(1, n + 1):
            shell(f"echo '{{id}}' > data/{wildcards.sample}/arbitrary/{id}.txt")



def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    checkpoints.generate_arbitrary.get(sample=wildcards.sample)
    ids = glob_wildcards(f"data/{wildcards.sample}/arbitrary/{{id}}.txt").id
    return expand(f"data/{wildcards.sample}/arbitrary/{{id}}.txt", id=ids)


rule append_hello:
    input:
        aggregate_input
    output:
        "data/{sample}/processed.txt"
    shell:
        "echo {input} 'hello' > {output}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I don't think that this is what I am after. In the checkpoint, the number of files are hardcoded (`n =3` or `n=2`). I am looking for a way to apply the rule append_hello to each file in each directory, without knowing beforehand, how many files are generated for each `sample`.

Comment: That is up to you how to generate the files. I've just provided an example where the same checkpoint obviously produces different number of files for different samples. That is not a requirement: your checkpoint may consist of a single `shell` section where the script does that work (and where nothing is hardcoded or could be easily predicted).

Comment: I am still confused: The desired output are ALL files individually, with a 'hello' appended. Could you expand on the function `aggregate_input`? What does this function do?

Comment: I guess my problem has to do with wildcards constraints. I would like to use `sample1/test1.txt`, etc. as wildcards in the form of `{sample}/{id}.txt`, but without using the product of `{sample}` and `{id}`. I need to tell snakemake to combine `sample1` with ids=[test1,test2,test3] and `sample2` with ids=[test1,test2].

Comment: If you need to output just `"hello"`, just do that: `f"echo 'hello' > data/{wildcards.sample}/arbitrary/{id}.txt"`. Wildcards constraints is another issue that should be avoided with separating the files into different directories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have definitively helped me getting the issue right, in particular with using checkpoint.